# JavaMail Gmail ConnectionTimeOut

Tags: java, gmail, imap, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap

I have this code and when i try to connect to Gmail, I am getting connection time out exception

```
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    try {
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "my.email.id", "eightasteriks");
```

P.S:

- I copied this code from Stackover flow thread.
- All the necessary libraries have been imported

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you are behind firewall or websense and it doesnt allow you to connect to gmail, can you check and make sure your firewall is allowing Java and your websense is not blocking gmail ?

Comment: for checking websense the easiest way is to check if you can access gmail from your browser, firewall which os you are on ?

Comment: I can open gmail and all the products related to Google. There are only 2 sites blocked and which are facebook and one more. This is the reason i am kind a confuse that when i can access gmail why can't i connect. I am on Windows XP

How can i check if the ports at which Java is connecting for imap is open for me?

Comment: I think it uses 25 as the default port, can you try setting a new port and then see if this still blocks

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has tips for debugging connection problems such as this.  You're almost certainly behind a firewall that only lets http connections through.

Comment: sweet .. so it turns out that my firewall are restricting me .. `telnet imap.gmail.com 143` ... `Connecting To imap.gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 143: Connect failed`